# Codeigniter 3 show_404 function issue - MY_Exception doesn't load

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception, error-handling, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter 3 and I want to custom the show_404() function.

Here is my main controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function otherMethod() {
        show_404();
    }

}
```

Added on my routes.php

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error/show_404_custom';
```

Created the controller Error.php with the method show_404_custom

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Error extends CI_Controller {

    public function show_404_custom() {
        $this->load->view('404_read_view');
    }
}
```

The 404_read_view.php view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Custom 404 page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I've tested with some undefined URL like:

```
/index.php/welcome/method_A
```

And I successfully get my Custom 404 page.

However, if I run a method that uses the `show_404()` function like:

```
/index.php/welcome/otherMethod
```

I oddly get the standard Codeigniter 404 page.

I've searched a bit and found out that I should Extend the Exception core class and override the show_404() function like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425433/4301970

So, I created the MY_Exceptions.php class inside /application/core:

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function show_404() {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->view('404_read_view');
        echo $CI->output->get_output();
        exit;
    }

}
```

And when I run the URL:

```
/index.php/welcome/otherMethod
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Exceptions' not found in (...)\system\core\Common.php on line 196
```

I took look inside Common.php and noticed that the load class function looks inside the libraries directory instead of core directory?

```
function &load_class($class, $directory = 'libraries', $param = NULL)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have tried to move the MY_Exceptions.php file to the libraries directory?

Comment: Yes, but strangely it's ignored and the default CI 404 page is shown.

Comment: I wrote a full guide in step by step to solve this issue at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42523178/5974902

Comment: `MY_Exceptions.php` is not complementary to `$route['404_override']`. Use one **OR** another. If you want to use `show_404()` then use your own `MY_Exceptions.php`, you don't need to override 404.

Answer (score 2):

use this, it's work in CI 3.1.4 (my latest project)

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->view('404_read_view');
        echo $CI->output->get_output();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use CI3 404_override cannot be in subfolder

Change

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error/show_404_custom'; 
// thinks its in subfolder
```

To

Location: application > controllers > Error.php

```
$route['404_override'] = 'error';
```

Controller

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Error extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() { // change to index
        $this->load->view('404_read_view');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi wolfgang1983! Changed but the problem persists.

Comment: 404_override "can" be used in sub folder. show_404() function doesn't use the route setting. I am using CI 3 and I confirmed that.